# Google Api Feed - Multi request

Tags: google-api

is it possible to request more than 1 Feed at the same time?

for example

```
google.load("feeds", "1",{"callback" : 'get_it(\'http://
www.fernsehkritik.tv/?feed=podcast\',\'1\'),get_it(\'http://rss.golem.de/rss.php?feed=RSS1.0\',\'99\')'});
```

or ...

```
 google.load("feeds", "1",{"callback" : 'get_it(\'http://
www.fernsehkritik.tv/?feed=podcast\',\'99\')'});
google.load("feeds", "1",{"callback" : 'get_it(\'http://rss.golem.de/
rss.php?feed=RSS1.0\',\'99\')'});
```

Both solutions are working but i am not sure, is this the right
(clean) way?

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think you're a slight bit confused at to what's going on.  When you call `google.load("feeds", "1",{"callback": "get_it('http://myfeed.com/whatever')"})`, you're not requesting that Google go load the feed at `http://myfeed.com/whatever`.  What you're saying is: "Hey, Google, load up the javascript to support your feed api, and when your feed api is all loaded and ready to use, call `get_it('http://myfeed.com/whatever')`, where presumably `get_it` is a function you've defined already in your page that uses Google's feed api to do its thing.

So I think your purpose would be better served by defining a single javascript function to execute one the feed is ready, something like:

```
function feed_api_ready() {
  get_it('http://www.fernsehkritik.tv/?feed=podcast', '99');
  get_it('http://rss.golem.de/rss.php?feed=RSS1.0', '99');
}
```

And then calling simply:

```
google.load("feeds", "1",{"callback" : 'feed_api_ready'})
```

That'll execute both "go get the feeds" functions right away when the Google API is all loaded.

Now, as for getting the feeds in parallel: believe it or not, that will also load the feeds in parallel. Javascript doesn't really have any ability to block and wait on network I/O, so anything in javascript that gets stuff from the network always has to be written in the form: "Go make this network request, and here's a function to call when you eventually get a response".  But in the meantime, the javascript engine on the browser keeps going without waiting for the response to come back.

This means that above, you'll fire off the request for `http://www.fernsehkritik.tv/?feed=podcast` and your browser will continue executing javascript without waiting for the network to respond, and you'll fire off the second request for `http://rss.golem.de/rss.php?feed=RSS1.0`.  So the network traffic for both feeds will then be coming back to your browser in parallel, even though javascript in the browser doesn't allow multiple threads of execution.